# Apache 2.4 Reverse Proxy using HTTPd

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-2.4, reverse-proxy

I created an AWS EC2 instance with a public IP, lets call it 100.0.0.0.

I added a rule for the security group to allow incoming HTTP traffic on port 80 for any IPv4.

I added to the config file in: `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass /test/ http://www.example.com/
    ProxyPassReverse /test/ http://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Which when I went to http://100.0.0.0/test/ ,
I got a 404 - Not Found displayed on my browser. Nothing in error_log.

I also tried this with a local host

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass /test/ http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse /test/ http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

&

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass /test/ http://127.0.0.1:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse /test/ http://127.0.0.1:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

Which gave me in the logs:

> Connection refused: AH00957: http: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:8080 (127.0.0.1) failed

> AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: 127.0.0.1, referer: http://100.0.0.0/

Since this is created with AWS I also tried creating an outbound rule, where I allowed any for IPv4.
Im not sure if I need to set any more rules in AWS, or if I missed a step configuring my proxy.

See doc I followed: https://linuxtechlab.com/apache-as-reverse-proxy-centos-rhel/

I also referenced: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html which lead me to the [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) example.

```
netstat -aon | grep 8080
TCP    0.0.0.0:8080           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       22304
TCP    [::]:8080              [::]:0                 LISTENING       22304
TCP    [::1]:8080             [::]:0                 LISTENING       25212
```

Comment: `Connection refused` indicates that nothing is listening on `127.0.0.1:8080`. Check if your service is actually running and if it is bound to the correct interface.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Would that be seeing a state of 'Established' using netstat in console?

Comment: Depends on the context. Why don't you show the complete output?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider see update on question

Comment: That doesn't say anything. Do you have a line that says state `LISTEN` for port 8080?

Comment: Check updates, I believe this is what we are looking for

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141120/discussion-between-travis-and-gerald-schneider).